# How to find an equation of the plane, given its normal vector and a point on the plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vectors

I have a question regarding vectors:

> Find the equation of the plane perpendicular to the vector $\vec{n}\space=(2,3,6)$ and which goes through the point $ A(1,5,3)$. (A cartesian and parametric equation).
>   Also find the distance between the beginning of axis and this plane.

I'm not really sure where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Suppose you take any point on the plane, say, $\vec{OR}$, where $O$ is the origin. Now, $\vec{AR}$ would be some sort of a line segment that lies on the plane.

But we know that this line segment must be perpendicular to $\space(2,3,6)$. This means that the dot product of $\vec{AR}$ (which is $\vec{OR} - \vec{OA}$) with $\space(2,3,6)$ must be equal to $0$. So we have:

$$(\vec{OR} - \vec{OA})\cdot \space(2,3,6) = 0,$$
$$\vec{OR}\cdot\space(2,3,6) = \vec{OA}\cdot(2,3,6).$$

But you know that $\vec{OA} = \space(1,5,3)$. Hence, the equation of the plane is:

$$\vec{OR}\cdot\space(2,3,6) = \space(1,5,3)\cdot\space(2,3,6),$$

$$\vec{OR}\cdot\space(2,3,6) = 35.$$

In Cartesian form, this is just

$$2x + 3y + 6z = 35.$$

Comment: pretty cool, thanks man

Comment: What is the O? What is OR? How is OR a point?

Comment: @Jwan622: O is the origin of the coordinate system (0, 0, 0). Any vector from the origin (e.g., X0, Y0, Z0), also define a Point in space (and vice versa).